# C code works when run with gdb but not normally

Tags: c, windows, debugging, gdb, cjson

My code only works if I run it with gdb:
gdb ./MyCode
run

and not if I just type:
./MyCode

This is the part of my code that is failing:

```
bool packageBuildFileDownload(char* receiver, char* finished, char* file_name, char* payload, char** json_string, size_t json_string_size) {
    cJSON* json = packageCreateJson();
    if (!json) return false;
        
    typedef struct PackageAttribute {
        char
            *name, 
            *value;
    } PackageAttribute;
    
    PackageAttribute attributes[] = {
        {
            .name = "type", 
            .value = "filedownload"
        }, 
        {
            .name = "receiver", 
            .value = receiver
        }, 
        {
            .name = "file_name", 
            .value = file_name
        }, 
        {
            .name = "finished", 
            .value = finished
        }, 
        {
            .name = "payload", 
            .value = payload
        }           
    };
    int attributes_size = sizeof(attributes) / sizeof(attributes[0]);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < attributes_size; i++) {
        if (!cJSON_AddStringToObject(json, attributes[i].name, attributes[i].value)) {
            cJSON_Delete(json);
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (!cJSON_PrintPreallocated(json, *json_string, json_string_size, false)) {
        // cJSON_PrintPreallocated returns failour 
        cJSON_Delete(json);
        return false;
    }
    
    cJSON_Delete(json);
    return true;
}

static bool filedownloadrequestSendResponse(Socket* socket, uint8_t* file_buffer, size_t file_buffer_size, char* receiver, char* finished, char* file_name) {
    char* b64_encode_buffer;
    base64Encode(file_buffer, file_buffer_size, &b64_encode_buffer);

    char* json_string = malloc(RESPONSE_PACKAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (!packageBuildFileDownload(receiver, finished, file_name, b64_encode_buffer, &json_string, strlen(json_string))) {
        free(json_string);
        return false;
    }
    
    free(b64_encode_buffer);
    
    CURLcode result = sendWs(socket->curl, json_string);
    free(json_string);
    if (result != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "sendWs() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(result));
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

My packageBuildFileDownload() function returns false because cJSON_PrintPreallocated is failing (cJSON_PrintPreallocated is part of the cJSON library). This only happends if I dont use gdb for some reason.

If you need more code please let me know :)

Comment: `strlen(json_string)` - undefined behaviour. `json_string` is not initialized. Use `RESPONSE_PACKAGE_BUFFER_SIZE` instead.

Comment: What might be happening is that GDB sets the process memory to zeros, making all pointer variable to become null-pointers. When you check for the null-pointers it works. When you don't run in GDB, the pointers are having an indeterminate value, that for your case happens to be different from null.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "What might be happening is that GDB sets the process memory to zeros" -- GDB _does no such thing_.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Thanks, I missed that and it solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My code only works if I run it with gdb:

GDB by default disables ASLR. Your code will probably stop working under GDB if you re-enable ASLR:

```
gdb ./MyCode run
(gdb) set disable-randomization off
(gdb) run
```

If enabling ASLR makes the program fail, it is exceedingly likely is failing due to using uninitialized memory.

And as Stanislav Volodarskiy commented, this is definitely a bug (and exactly the reading of uninitialized memory bug at that):

```
char* json_string = malloc(RESPONSE_PACKAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);
if (!packageBuildFileDownload(..., &json_string, strlen(json_string))) {
```

To fix that bug, do this:

```
char* json_string = malloc(RESPONSE_PACKAGE_BUFFER_SIZE);
if (!packageBuildFileDownload(..., &json_string, RESPONSE_PACKAGE_BUFFER_SIZE)) {
```